# Функция ExtractIconEx

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, delphi-7, delphi-xe

Добрый день, уважаемые программисты! Написал процедуру для извлечения иконок. Всё работает, но не смог до конца разобраться с функцией:

> ExtractIconEx

Конкретно меня интересует, каким должен быть массив

> WideChars: array[0..1000] of WideChar;

```
var Minicon: array[1..500] of TIcon;
    Maxicon: array[1..500] of TIcon;

procedure LoadIcons(fname: String; lgImages, smImages: TImageList);
var smIconHandle, lgIconHandle: HICON;
    i: integer;
    WideChars: array[0..1000] of WideChar;    {поставил 1000, потому что при малых значениях выдает ошибку}
begin
  i:=0;
  while Integer(ExtractIconEx(StringToWideChar(fname, WideChars, Length(fname)+1),i,lgIconHandle,smIconHandle,1))>0 do
  begin
    inc(i);
    maxicon[i]:=TIcon.Create;
    maxicon[i].Handle:=lgIconHandle;
    lgImages.AddIcon(maxicon[i]);

    minicon[i]:=TIcon.Create;
    minicon[i].Handle:=smIconHandle;
    smImages.AddIcon(minicon[i]);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Это вы не разобрались с функцией `StringToWideChar`, а не `ExtractIconEx`. Массив `WideChars` (буфер) должен быть достаточного размера, чтобы туда влезла ваша строка `fname`. Должно быть как-то так:

```
var
  WideChars: array of WideChar;
begin
  SetLength(WideChars, Length(fname) + SizeOf(WideChar)); // на один символ больше для "terminated by a NULL wide character"
  StringToWideChar(fname, WideChars, Length(WideChars));
```

Хотя функция эта вам не нужна, делайте так:

```
ExtractIconEx(PChar(fname), i, lgIconHandle, smIconHandle, 1)
```

Не забудьте вызвать `DestroyIcon` для каждой иконки извлеченной этой функцией.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci DestroyIcon необходимо вызвать в момент уничтожения формы?

Comment: @АлександрЪ в тот момент, когда она вам больше не нужна. Если она все время отображается на форме, то да - в момент уничтожения формы.